# How to configure a dense output layer for a multivariate, multi-step LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am trying to predict the trajectory of an object in 3 dimensions several steps into the future given a time series of measurements. I am starting with a toy problem shown below with three sequences. My goal is to have a series of predictions from 1 to n_steps_out for each coordinate. However, I am unable to configure the output dense layer and I think I am missing something conceptually.

In this toy example, I end up with a total of 5 examples, 2 prediction steps with 3 features, and I get a Value Error of 
"ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (5, 2, 3)"

Thank you in advance for any guidance you can give me

'''

```
# multivariate multi-step stacked lstm example
from numpy import array
from numpy import hstack
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dense

# split a multivariate sequence into samples
def split_sequences(sequences, n_steps_in, n_steps_out):
    X, y = list(), list()
    for i in range(len(sequences)):
        # find the end of this pattern
        end_ix = i + n_steps_in
        out_end_ix = end_ix + n_steps_out
        # check if we are beyond the dataset
        if out_end_ix > len(sequences):
            break
        # gather input and output parts of the pattern
        seq_x, seq_y = sequences[i:end_ix, :], sequences[end_ix:out_end_ix,:]
        X.append(seq_x)
        y.append(seq_y)
    return array(X), array(y)

# define input sequence training data
in_seq1 = array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
in_seq2 = array([2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18])
in_seq3 = array([3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27])
# convert to [rows, columns] structure
in_seq1 = in_seq1.reshape((len(in_seq1), 1))
in_seq2 = in_seq2.reshape((len(in_seq2), 1))
in_seq3 = in_seq3.reshape((len(in_seq3), 1))
# horizontally stack columns
dataset = hstack((in_seq1, in_seq2, in_seq3))
# choose a number of time steps
n_steps_in, n_steps_out = 3, 2
# covert into input/output
X, y = split_sequences(dataset, n_steps_in, n_steps_out)
# the dataset knows the number of features, e.g. 2
print(X.shape, y.shape)
# summarize the data
for i in range(len(X)):
    print(X[i], y[i])
n_features = X.shape[2]

# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, input_shape=(n_steps_in, n_features)))
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(n_steps_out))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
# fit model
model.fit(X, y, epochs=10, verbose=1)
# demonstrate prediction
x_input = array([[10, 20, 30], [11, 22, 33 ], [12, 24, 36]])
x_input = x_input.reshape((1, n_steps_in, n_features))
yhat = model.predict(x_input, verbose=0)
print(yhat)
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

So, this is the way I see it.

In

```
model.fit(X,y...)
```

your y  is a vector with the coordinates of the trajectory correct? (Lenght 3)
whilst in your last layer you have your dense layer like so:

```
Dense(2)
```

because n_steps_out = 2

You will need to change this to 3 because you are trying to predict three values, to get this to build. However, it seems to me that you have misunderstood how this LSTM model should be implemented (or, you are doing it a way that is unknown to me)